# how to change the period of clock in Model sim

Tags: vhdl

I would like to change my period of clock from 0,1ns to 5ns. Anybody now how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Is this a VHDL question or a Modelsim question? Can one generate clocks in Modelsim? If so, might it be easier to create a testbench in VHDL to generate input stimulus? I think we need more information.

Comment: If your clock generator is `clk <= not clk after Clk_Period/2;` simply change the declaration of `Clk_Period` to `constant Clk_Period : time := 5 ns;` (but note that if  Modelsim's timestep is set to 1 ns, `Clk_Period/2` will be rounded down to 2 ns.)

Comment: This is a ModelSim question. I dont know how to configure the software to change the periodes

Comment: It is a much better idea to write a testbench and generate your clock that way. Then you have complete control and you are not tied to a particular technology. I have been designing ICs and FPGAs off and on (mostly on) for 27 years. I expect it is at least 23 since I did anything similar to what you're trying to do; it's just very old-fashioned.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you'd like to change `Timeline Properties`, but not clock period. So you should click (Right Mouse Button) on Timeline, select `Grid & Timeline Properties` and then choose necessary values.

[image]